# OLS - Concept - inconsistency - which assumptions fail?

Tags: least-squares, econometrics, consistency

What are practical scenarios where consistency will fail and which assumption/s that is/are violated?

Is this due to an inherent fault in sampling the data or in the data-generating process? Can I fix this with strategies to avoid an inconsistent estimator in such cases?

Comment: One big category: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endogeneity_(econometrics)

Comment: Here I would say that it is the DGP as adding observations does not fix the problem; increasing sample size could make the problem worse, or?

Comment: Consistency fails if we have OMV, measurement errors and simultaneity. Is there a away to fix this? Could IV solve the issue? I would think yes.